# Get Int32 from Span<byte>

Tags: c#

Been researching spans, memory etc . I'm trying to understand the intended method for getting an int out of a Span

Of all the blog posts I've read there was hinting of a `NonPortableCast<T>` method being implemented, but it appears that it has been removed.

I also read about it potentially being renamed to `.Cast<T>` on one of Marc Gravell's posts but again, I cant find it anywhere.

So given:

```
public ReadOnlySpan<byte> MessageBytes {get;set;}
public ReadOnlySpan<byte> ItemLengthBytes => MessageBytes.Slice(0,4);
```

How do I convert those 4 bytes to an int?

Here is what Im doing now, is this the correct way? Or is there a faster way?

```
public int ItemLength => Convert.ToInt32(ItemLengthBytes.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the most recent bits, the `Cast` method is now under [`System.Runtime.InteropServices.MemoryMarshal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.memorymarshal.cast?view=net-6.0#System_Runtime_InteropServices_MemoryMarshal_Cast__2_System_ReadOnlySpan___0__).

But if you intend to read out a single int, you probably want the [`Read`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.memorymarshal.read?view=net-6.0) method on that same type.

as such:

```cs
public int ItemLength => MemoryMarshal.Read<int>(ItemLengthBytes);
```

There's also [`BitConverter.ToInt32`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.toint32?view=net-6.0#System_BitConverter_ToInt32_System_ReadOnlySpan_System_Byte__), which is more analagous to the older `Convert` apis.

```cs
public int ItemLength => BitConverter.ToInt32(ItemLengthBytes);
```

What you wrote will work as well, but it will lose a lot of the performance advantage of the Span, since you'll do an extra memory copy and heap allocation every time you use `ToArray()`.

Comment: Thanks! Is this something you stumbled on? Or do you follow a blog or something where you saw it? Just trying to keep up with things :)

Comment: To be honest, I don't remember where i saw that particular change, just that it had moved. It was probably me checking the [API Diffs](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/2.1/api-diff/2.0-vs-2.1.md) when .Net core 2.1 was announced. Looking there now, I see that another option would be to use [BitConverter.ToInt32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.toint32?view=netcore-2.2#System_BitConverter_ToInt32_System_ReadOnlySpan_System_Byte__) which is more directly analogous to Convert.ToInt32.