# Fastest way to transform ReadonlySpan<byte> to int?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a file with a string `"40070"`, I read it and transform it to a `ReadonlySpan<byte>` variable with `52, 48, 48, 55, 48` inside. This Span represents the number `40070`. How can I cast/transform that `ReadonlySpan<byte>` back to an int?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't it the same as? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639586/converting-byte-array-to-int - answer 4 seems promosing

Comment: Why does your span have 5 bytes when you want a 4 byte `int`? Do you want to ignore the last byte or something?

Comment: Either way, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54271885/5133585) should help, if not a dupe.

Comment: Because the ReadonlySpan<byte> was sliced from a string, so that byte in theory is a char type

Comment: Doesn't really output the "desired" result: https://dotnetfiddle.net/LvBYQV

Comment: @Sweeper asker wants the bytes interpreted as ASCII character codes!

Comment: You are probably not looking for samething like this https://dotnetfiddle.net/OpVQXp

Comment: why aren't you looking for `ReadOnlySpan<byte>` to `string`? and than simply parse the `string` to `int`? https://dotnetfiddle.net/dg4u8o

Comment: I'm extracting numbers from a huge file, so whenever I find a ReadonlySpan<byte> that represents a number, I have to cast it to an int. Dohnal, your solution works, but I'm wondering if there is not  a one line solution that relies in a .Net API

Comment: prolly because 1) it takes memory 2) even worst .. C# string are 2 byte long 3) it takes time ..

Comment: Thanks, and trying not to be annoying, but is there any way where we don't allocate any memory and rely on Span instrinsics?

Comment: `System.Buffers.Text.Utf8Parser` ?

Comment: if you had `ReadOnlySpan<char>` you could have used `TryFormat` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryformat?view=net-7.0

Comment: System.Buffers.Text.Utf8Parser worked like a charm, thanks!

Comment: But generally it is the Vojtěch Dohnal code :D https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Buffers/Text/Utf8Parser/Utf8Parser.Integer.Unsigned.N.cs#L53 ... so if you know that your span contains only integer as string without sign/dots/etc it will be faster

Comment: out of curiosity did you run the horses, or just used the most fancy looking one? https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: @RandRandom Accepted is the fastest - see here https://dotnetfiddle.net/HEenrR

Comment: @RandRandom But not really, the results in fiddle are wrong in debug, the first code I posted in comments was in fact the fastest https://stackoverflow.com/q/76162739/2224701.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ReadOnlySpan<byte> data = stackalloc byte[] { 52, 48, 48, 55, 48 };
// ^^^ or however you're getting your span; that part doesn't matter

if (System.Buffers.Text.Utf8Parser.TryParse(data, out int value, out int bytes))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Parsed {bytes} bytes into value: {value}");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read the initial data as chars, or convert the bytes into span of chars and use `int.Parse/TryParse`:

```cs
ReadOnlySpan<byte> span = new byte[] { 52, 48, 48, 55, 48 };
Span<char> chars = stackalloc char[span.Length];
Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(span, chars);
var result = int.Parse(chars);
Console.WriteLine(result); // prints "40070"
```