# Why is internal .NET method so much faster than simpler code copied from .NET open source?

Tags: c#, .net, performance-testing, .net-fiddle

I have following code based [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76153627/fastest-way-to-transform-readonlyspanbyte-to-int/).
Fiddle here. https://dotnetfiddle.net/vchYHj

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ReadOnlySpan<byte> r = stackalloc byte[] { 52, 48, 48, 55, 48 };
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        int result = 0;


        sw.Restart();
        for (int i=0; i<10000000; i++) result =  Test1(r);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"Test1 took {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms {result}");


        sw.Restart();
        for (int i=0; i<10000000; i++) result = Test2(r);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"Test2 took {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms {result}");

    }

    public static int Test1(ReadOnlySpan<byte> source)
    {
        int answer = 0;
        int index = 0;
        int c = source[index];
        answer = c - '0';
        while (true)
        {
            index++;
            if ((uint)index >= (uint)source.Length)
                break;
            c = source[index];
            answer = answer * 10 + c - '0';
        }
         return answer;
    }
    
    public static int Test2(ReadOnlySpan<byte> data)
    {
        if (System.Buffers.Text.Utf8Parser.TryParse(data, out int value, out int bytes))
        {
            return(value);
        }   
        else
            return(0);
    }
}
```

> Test1 took 244ms 40070
> Test2 took 99ms 40070

Why is the second method `Test1` so much slower on .NET fiddle, when it is copied exactly from .NET open source and is even much simpler?

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Buffers/Text/Utf8Parser/Utf8Parser.Integer.Unsigned.N.cs#L53

Comment: You cannot get reliable benchmarks by using `Stopwatch` and .NET Fiddle also isn't made for benchmarking, either. You should use an appropriate .NET benchmarking tool instead, e.g. [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet).

Comment: Then you obviously also mean "first method" in _"Why is the second method Test1 so much slower"_, right?

Comment: @ewerspej Do you believe that using that tool would completely reverse the results...?

Comment: `System.Buffers.Text.Utf8Parser` lives in an optimized assembly. Your code runs in debug mode.

Comment: Why do you even care? If you need 10mio iterations to get a difference of 150ms, I won't argue `Test2` to be "much slower than `Test1`".

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal .NET Fiddle won't give reliable results since we have just one web server and everyone's code executes on it. So when your's code executes there, there is a big chance that other's code executes there the same time as well and it might affect your results

Comment: @ewerspej really it does: Test1 took 74ms 40070
Test2 took 143ms 40070

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal Not sure what you want to tell me with that. I merely pointed out that you should make sure to take a valid benchmarking approach, because otherwise the results are meaningless. I believe you that there is a difference between those tests, I cannot say why that is the case.

Comment: @ewerspej Just confirming you were right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is the second method Test1 so much slower on .NET fiddle,

One reason would be that code compiled by .NET fiddle code is not optimized. As a simple example, consider that the following code

```
#if DEBUG
    Console.WriteLine("DEBUG");
#else
    Console.WriteLine("RELEASE");
#endif
```

will print `DEBUG` when executed with .NET fiddle.

If you want to do benchmarks, I recommend reading Eric Lippert's [blog series](https://ericlippert.com/tag/benchmarks/) on that topic first. Benchmarking the Debug build instead of the Release build is just one of the common mistakes listed there.

Comment: yes in realase are the results reversed Test1 took 72ms 
Test2 took 141ms.

Comment: And the .NET Fiddle server is probably doing a lot of other things in parallel, making a precise time measurement impossible.

Answer (score 2):

You can see the original code here: [Utf8Parser.TryParse](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Buffers/Text/Utf8Parser/Utf8Parser.Integer.Signed.cs#L139). This method then calls [TryParseInt32D](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Buffers/Text/Utf8Parser/Utf8Parser.Integer.Signed.D.cs#L194) which does the heavy work and is highly optimized.

The code is ugly and unwraps loops and uses goto's. Very interesting and totally okay in a library used by millions of people, but this is not how you should write code.

They certainly made a lot of benchmarks to figure out which optimizations work best. If you want a very fast code, you cannot just assume your code will be fast. It depends on a lot of factors like how your code is translated to IL, how this IL is translated native code, how much 1st level cache your CPU has, etc., etc.